# Is it possible to configure spdlog from a file like log4j or log4cxx?

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx, spdlog

I have experience of log4j, and have used a port of it called log4net in c#. In both cases I find it very useful to configure loggers at run time, by means of logger config files. For example you can increase the log level of a particular subsystem without a recompile.

I am searching for a logging framework for c++. Currently checking log4cxx and spdlog.
I see that log4cxx can read its configuration from an xml file.
Does this ability to configure at run time exist for spdlog?

Answer (score 2):

There is https://github.com/guangie88/spdlog_setup to configure spdlog using TOML

Comment: The project does not seem active anymore (last commit 2 years ago). The C++20 compatibility, for example, is not available.